# Do RepeatModeler results contain functional domains?

Tags: genome, sequence-annotation, repeat-elements

The repeat families predicted by [RepeatModeler](https://www.pnas.org/content/117/17/9451) contain known transposable elements (TEs) and unknown ones.

How do we know whether some of these may actually:

- within a functional domain of a gene or
- represent a functional domain?

Could it be predicted because repeats may simply due to this domain appeared in multiple gene loci?
Thanks.